# Create a empty array inside a Gremlin traversal?

Tags: gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

This sounds silly but is there a way to create a empty array inside a Gremlin traversal?

For the query below:

```
g.V().has('person','name', 'marko').project('a', 'b').by().by()
```

I want to project `b` as an empty array. I have tried:

```
g.V().has('person','name', 'marko').project('a', 'b').by().by(constant("").fold())
```

But `constant("").fold()` is not actually empty `constant("").fold().count()` returns 1. This applies to `constant(null).fold()` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty array/collection would actually be a `fold()` of nothing. You'll get nothing if you filter everything, hence:

```
g.V().has('person','name','marko').
  project('a', 'b').
    by().
    by(__.not(identity()).fold())
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for

```
g.withSideEffect('x',[]).V().has('person','name','marko').project('a','b').by(select('x')).by('name')

==>[a:[],b:marko]
```

Comment: This works but just curious, is there a way to have the `withSideEffect` inside the `by`?